# RegExp repeated groups

Tags: regex

I have a string:

> 10-02;34-05;

Elements like dd-dd can be repeated many times:

> 10-02;34-05;12-02;23-05;10-42;44-05

At the end of the string the symbol `;` can be optional but between elements dd-dd the symbol `;` should be mandatory.

I tried ti build regular expression `/^([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[;])+$/)` but it covers cases like `10-02;34-05;12-02;23-05;10-42;44-05` but not `10-02;34-05;12-02;23-05;10-42;44-05;` with the symbol `;` at the end.

How Do I have to build an regular expression to cover both of cases.

Thanks.

Comment: Some of your input `12-012` is not `\d\d-\d\d`. It is `\d{2}-\d{2,3}`

Comment: thanks but it's typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `^(?:\d{2}-\d{2}(?:;|$))+$`

Which means:

```
^               # start of line
(?:             # non-capturing group
    \d{2}       # match 2 digits
    -           # match a hyphen
    \d{2}       # match 2 digits
    (?:;|$)     # match ; or end of line
)+              # repeat 1 or more times
$               # end of line
```

**Note**

```
10-02;34-05;12-012;23-05;10-42;44-05;
                ^--- You have 3 digits here ??? If so change all {2} to +
```

[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dC0sQ9)

Comment: Actually I believe this regexp doesn't allow for lines that end in `;`, since you force that the end of line excludes the option of the semicolon.

Comment: @cgledezma There is an online demo, try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `?` to optionally match a pattern

```
^\d{2}-\d{2}(;\d{2}-\d{2})*;?$
```

or

```
^(\d{2}-\d{2};)*(\d{2}-\d{2};?)$
```

Answer (score 2):

This is about as simply/briefly as you can express it:

```
^(\d\d-\d\d(;|$))+$
```

Comment: Actually this regular expression will return a match inside, for example, this string: `10-02;34-05;12-12;23-05;10-42;44-05;lzqejbg`, which would be incorrect. For it to actually work you have request an end of line after the pattern, like the answer that was accepted.

Comment: @cgledezma a) ' it depends what language. Java's `String.matches()` for example must match the *whole* input to match (start and end are implied and not necessary), and since language has not been specified, end may not be needed b) if end is needed, start must also be needed too. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
^(\d{2}-\d{2};)*\d{2}-\d{2}(;)?$
```

The `?`operator makes the last parenthized expression optional, like placing a `{0, 1}` after it.